# WCF Rest - mixing HTTP and HTTPS in one ServiceContract

Tags: wcf, http, ssl, https, webhttpbinding

I currently have a Http Rest WCF4 service, defined by the ServiceContract `IEventService` which is exposed only over HTTP.

I have been tasked with making **some** of the OperationContracts to work only over HTTPS So I have split those methods into a seperate ServiceContract called `IEventServiceHTTPS`

Hosting this on my dev box using IIS7.5 with a self-signed certificate, the methods which are part of the `IEventServiceHTTPS` are called fine over HTTPS and not over HTTP, as expected.

However the HTTP methods exposed by `IEventService` now do not work.

I get the following when trying to access the HTTP methods:

```
HTTP Error 403.4 - Forbidden
The page you are trying to access is secured with Secure Sockets Layer (SSL).
```

web.config with my changes:

```
<system.serviceModel>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true">
      <serviceActivations>
        <add service="Api.EventService" relativeAddress="EventService.svc" factory="Api.UnityServiceHostFactory"/>
      </serviceActivations>
    </serviceHostingEnvironment>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="Api.EventServiceBehavior">
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpsGetEnabled="true"/>
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true"/>
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
      <endpointBehaviors>
        <behavior name="WebBehavior">
          <webHttp/>
        </behavior>
      </endpointBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <services>
      <service behaviorConfiguration="Api.EventServiceBehavior" name="Api.EventService">
        <endpoint address="" binding="webHttpBinding" behaviorConfiguration="WebBehavior" bindingConfiguration="webBindingHTTP" contract="Api.IEventService"/>
        **<endpoint address="" binding="webHttpBinding" behaviorConfiguration="WebBehavior" bindingConfiguration="webBindingHTTPS" contract="Api.IEventServiceHTTPS"/>**
      </service>
    </services>
    <bindings>
      <webHttpBinding>
        <binding name="webBindingHTTP">
          <security mode="None"></security>
        </binding>
        **<binding name="webBindingHTTPS">
          <security mode="Transport">
          </security>
        </binding>**
      </webHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
  </system.serviceModel>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this error is originating because of IIS vdir [SSL settings]-> Require SSL -> true. If you want both http and https endpoints accessible in the same service then uncheck this setting as this will prevent you from doing unsecure http in the vdir.